# What will future generations condemn us for?

Tags: ethics, social-ethics

I can think of the following:

1. Human-created mass extinctions
2. Industrial meat production
3. Institutionalisation and isolation of the elderly
4. Environment destruction

What are other contemporary society’s moral blind spots?

Comment: I reformatted this as I think you intended. You may roll it back or further edit by clicking on the "edited" link above. Welcome to this SE! I think your number 2 will be the main one expanded to general dietary issues.

Comment: Never mind future generations it's possible to be condemnatory right now. It's not like we don't know what we're doing and must wait to find out.

Comment: Pretending not to notice as a few powerful people laid the plans for world war 3.

Comment: The OP may want to consult some of the writings of Norwegian philosopher Arne Naess. You can also spread some of your concerns over earth science and biology here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole of of the way we live will seem shocking in every detail. Simply consider a ten or fifteen thousand year period. Morality, the whole of human behavior, is a function of what is believed to be possible. For instance, the more the weather becomes seen as technologically controllable, the more a small but growing part of the population conceives a burning resentment for those human powers that allow disasters and droughts and so forth. However, formulating deeper unfoldings leads to annihilation of the possibility of projecting ourselves into them. The more the biological substratum comes available to conscience manipulation the more inconceivable the manipulations we can't yet foresee become. For instance, such things that have long been imagined, such as meat made in laboratories rather than slaughtered which obviate harming brute creatures. Elimination of the elderly through putting a stop to aging, and reversing aging. But, it is all so multifarious one can't suppose anything like this kind of consideration will exist. The sheer strangeness is outside our ability to project ourselves intelligently and at future no one will any longer regard human beings as themselves (even more so than today no one considers themselves some distant sea going ancestor of the human as it will not merely be a matter of Evolution, but radical technology and whatever follows as the next and genuine successor to Science) or worth "condemning". The conception of condemnation will have long ceased to exist and unconstrained forces will focus on points utterly alien to our own time.